# How to run python file in cron job

Tags: python, command-line, cron

I need to run this file:

```
from apps.base.models import Event
from apps.base.models import ProfileActiveUntil
from django.template import Context
from django.db.models import Q
import datetime
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from bonzer.settings import SITE_HOST
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from bonzer.settings import send_mail, BONZER_MAIL, BONZER_MAIL_SMTP, BONZER_MAIL_USER,         BONZER_MAIL_PASS, BONZER_MAIL_USETLS


today = datetime.date.today()
monthAgo = today + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
monthAgoMinusOneDay = today + datetime.timedelta(days=2)
events = Event.objects.all()
ProfileActiveUntils = ProfileActiveUntil.objects.filter(Q(active_until__range=(monthAgo, monthAgoMinusOneDay)))
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = "Novim dogodivscinam naproti"
msg['From'] = BONZER_MAIL
msg['To'] = 'jjag3r@gmail.com'

text = u'bla'
html = u'bla'
send_mail(msg_to=msg['To'], msg_subject=msg['Subject'], msg_html=html, msg_text=text)
```

I execute it like this: `*/2 * * * * /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /home/nezap/webapps/bonzer/bonzer/apps/base/alert.py`

But I get error: No module named apps.base.models.

Important fact is that I can't install virtualenv on server because I don't have permissions. Also I'm kind of newbie on this stuff so I don't have a lot of skills on servers or python.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume this is a problem with your cwd (current working directory). An easy way to test this would be to go to the root (cd /) then run:

```
python2.7 /home/nezap/webapps/bonzer/bonzer/apps/base/alert.py
```

You should get the same error. The path you will want to use will depend on the place where you normally run the script from. I would guess it would either be:

/home/nezap/webapps/bonzer/bonzer/apps/base

or

/home/nezap/webapps/bonzer/bonzer/

So your solution would either be:

```
*/2 * * * * cd /home/nezap/webapps/bonzer/bonzer/apps/base && /usr/local/bin/python2.7 ./alert.py
```

or

```
*/2 * * * * cd /home/nezap/webapps/bonzer/bonzer && /usr/local/bin/python2.7 ./apps/base/alert.py
```

basically you are telling cron to change directory to that path, then if that works(the &&) run the following command.

Answer (score 2):

`cron` does not read rc shell files so you need to define the enviroment variable PYTHONPATH to include the location of the `apps` package and all other module files that are required by the script.

```
PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7:/usr/lib/python2.7
*/2 * * * * /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /home/nezap/webapps/bonzer/bonzer/apps/base/alert.pyr
```